# install auto-gptq not working despite torch installed (error torch is not installed, please install torch first!)

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to install auto-gptq locally, and I receive this error:

```
Collecting auto-gptq
  Using cached auto_gptq-0.3.2.tar.gz (63 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 4294967295
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      torch is not installed, please install torch first!
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 4294967295
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I installed torch:

```
PS > C:\...\python.exe -m pip install torch        
Requirement already satisfied: torch in c:\... (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock in c:\... (from torch) (3.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in c:\... (from torch) (4.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: sympy in c:\... (from torch) (1.12)
Requirement already satisfied: networkx in c:\... (from torch) (3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in c:\... (from torch) (3.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in c:\... (from jinja2->torch) (2.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: mpmath>=0.19 in c:\... (from sympy->torch) (1.3.0)
```

But still I receive the error. Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

To solve the problem, I used the following:

```
pip install auto_gptq==0.2.0
```

as maybe the new version of `auto_gptq` is not supported well.

Answer (score 1):

#### **Installing `auto-gptq` on Windows:**

You can install **`auto-gptq`** on Windows using the following **`pip`** command:

```bash
pip install auto-gptq --extra-index-url https://huggingface.github.io/autogptq-index/whl/cu117/
```

Make sure to replace **`cu117`** with the appropriate CUDA if needed.

#### **Installing `auto-gptq` on Linux:**

For Linux, you can use the following set of commands:

```bash
# Download the wheel file
wget -q https://github.com/PanQiWei/AutoGPTQ/releases/download/v0.4.1/auto_gptq-0.4.1+cu118-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl

# Install the wheel file
BUILD_CUDA_EXT=0 pip install -qqq auto_gptq-0.4.1+cu118-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl --progress-bar off
```

Make sure to replace **`cu118`** and **`cp310`** with the appropriate CUDA and Python versions if needed.

#### **Installing `auto-gptq` on Colab or Kaggle Notebooks:**

here you can execute the Linux commands with a preceding exclamation mark:

```bash
!wget -q https://github.com/PanQiWei/AutoGPTQ/releases/download/v0.4.1/auto_gptq-0.4.1+cu118-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl
!BUILD_CUDA_EXT=0 pip install -qqq auto_gptq-0.4.1+cu118-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl --progress-bar off
```

This allows you to run the Linux commands directly in the notebook environment.

This works for me for these 3 different cases.

Comment: which os you use @IshanHettiarachchi

Comment: I Updated the Answer with what works for me on Linux. Also, make sure to use the appropriate CUDA. @IshanHettiarachchi

Comment: Tried with Windows 10

Comment: Are you sure you have a GPU and installed CUDA then check the CUDA version you have downloaded?